# Error using SqlCommand

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I have added some data from an Excel spreadsheet to a `DataGridView`.
I am using this code to save the data to a database in SQL Server.

`Country` and `Currency` are of type `VARCHAR` and `rate` is `Float`. The data is successfully added but I have an error message from the `SqlCommand` line.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=NIFAL;Initial Catalog=Currency;Integrated Security=True;");

    foreach (DataGridViewRow Row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO CurrencyTable(Country, Currency, Rate) VALUES('" + Row.Cells[0].Value.ToString()
```

+ "', '" + Row.Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "', '" +  Row.Cells[2].Value.ToString() + "')", con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
        }

Comment: Building SQL commands with string concatenation instead of parametrized queries not only introduce SQL injection, but also pretty much impossible to get right. Any particular reason you need to go such painful route?

Comment: Why are you opening and closing the connection for each row? Open the connection once, before the foreach and close it after the loop has finished. The performance will be massively improved.

Answer (score 3):

Sanitizing input is important, and you probably has some error in your input. I would try and get the error messages listed, here is sample code that uses a "using" statment, parameters and sends the error to the trace listener(s)

```
     using (var con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=NIFAL;Initial Catalog=Currency;Integrated Security=True;"))
        {
            con.Open();
            foreach (var Row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                var cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO CurrencyTable(Country, Currency, Rate) VALUES(@country, @currency, @rate)",con);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@country", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = Row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@currency", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = Row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@rate", SqlDbType.Float).Value = Row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                try
                {
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception err)
                {
                    //You should here mark the row that has an error and output the error message 
                    Row.Cells[3].Value = err.Message;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Just use `cmd.Parameters.Add("@Country", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)` - no need to explicitly create a `new SqlParameter()` ....